# TV series where boy with glider visits world in another dimension

Tags: story-identification, tv

I am looking for the name of a TV series that I watched quite a long time ago.

I vaguely remember the topic. It was about a boy with a delta glider flying around. He somehow goes through a dimension door and finds himself in another world where he gets into various adventures. His goal is to return home.

It is not animated. I would say from 1980s.

Comment: animated? country of origin (or viewing)? languages in program? what is a 'long time ago': 1960s vs 1980s?

Comment: Was it more time travel?  Try this [YouTube clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bTOXB9Orzv0).

Comment: If it wasn't for the delta glider I'd suggest Sliders...

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like the [Winners](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0248656/) episode **"Quest Beyond Time"**

> *A young hang glider crash lands into the year 2457 where he finds
>   himself embarking on a dangerous mission to help an ailing colony.*

[Eshier](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/171715/looking-for-the-name-of-a-tv-series/171717#comment460455_171715) was kind enough to provide a clip showing the hang-glider the boy uses.

Comment: It was so long time ago I can't tell. I need to watch a few episodes. Thanks for the pointer.